# Find the number of arrangements that can be made of the letters of the word 'DIFFERENT' without changing the place of a vowel?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My procedure :

The word given is 'DIFFERENT'

The condition that the position of a vowel cannot be changed means that permutations of vowels will not be counted. So I have cancelled $3$ letters 'I' , 'E' and 'E' because they are not part of my condition.
So now we have total $6$ numbers, out of them $2$ are common i.e.,'F ', 'F'.

After calculation, I got the result $360$.

> $\dfrac{6!}{2!}= 360$ ; here '!' Indicates factorial

But in my book the result is given $359$, Can anyone help to find where I have made a mistake? Or you can do the full math and show me how you obtained $359$?

Comment: They are probably just not counting the “identity” rearrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct, maybe they have excluded DIFFERENT itself by the counting.

Comment: 359 is correct?

Comment: @user70421 Your evaluation is correct they are 360 with DIFFERENT itself (since 6!/2! take into account also this arrangement) and thus they are 359 if we exclude DIFFERENT.

Comment: Ah ha I got it , I got it so they excluded DIFFERENT from total arrangement . Thanks

Comment: Yes it is a bit strange indeed!